# Select name based on ID with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I create a new form and I want view name based on id in another table, but the id can't view in the dropdown list:

[image]

This is the view:

```
<div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">ID Operator</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("idOp", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idOp, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-2">Name</label>
        <div class="control-label col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.tbl_operator.nama, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.tbl_operator.nama , "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
</div>
```

This is the controller :

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.idEx = new SelectList(db.tbl_exercises, "idEx");
    ViewBag.idOp = new SelectList(db.tbl_operator, "idOp");
    return View();
}
```

Maybe I'm missing the code.

Answer (score 0):

You need choose what field is `Name`, `Value` for `SelectList` like

```
ViewBag.idEx = new SelectList(tbl_exercises, "Value", "Name");
```

I made an example base on your code

```
var tbl_exercises = new List<exercises>
{
                new exercises
                {
                    Name = "Name 1",
                    Value = 10
                },
                new exercises
                {
                    Name = "Name 2",
                    Value = 11
                }
  };

  ViewBag.idEx = new SelectList(tbl_exercises, "Value", "Name");
```

Comment: but in the textbox name still not value

Answer (score 0):

`SelectList` is defined as

```
public SelectList(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField);
```

In your controller, try to use

```
ViewBag.idOp = new SelectList(db.tbl_operator, "idOp","idOp");
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, sir @Ryan but in the textbox still not value when i choose the ID on the dropdown list